# How to share class library between Xamarin and Asp.net core?

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, compatibility, portable-class-library

Is there any way I can reference to some type of class library on Asp.net core and Xamarin at the same time? I want to use some core code in Web API and on phone app. 
PS. It looks like PCL doesn't work for me.

Comment: So does class library .net works with xamarin?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes I believe the best way to share code between server and xamarin for now is .net standard projects.

Answer (score 1):

PCL is working fine. You can select Profile111 which includes Android, iOS and ASP.NET Core beside others as shown in image:

[image]

Comment: is there support for dnx libraries??

Comment: @Matt when I select that platforms I get "The project's targets cannot be changed. The selected targets require the project opt-into NuGet 3.0 support, however, Visual Studio cannot automatically do this for you. Please uninstall all NuGet packages and try again." But I already have NuGet 3.0 by using VS2015 SP2. Tried on another PC, still the same issue.

Comment: @Matt btw all NuGet packages are uninstalled, but something forbid targets swithing for me.

Comment: @Matt I tried to do pretty much the same, [but am stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274240/how-to-use-pcl-in-asp-net-core-1-0-rc2-project) - did you manage to get it to work with RC2 bits as well?

Comment: Profile111 does not support ASP.NET core.

Comment: I just created a new project, made sure, asp.net core is checked and looked in csproj. It says Profile111... so please explain your "does not support"

Comment: ".NET Standard 2.0 libraries are recommended over Portable Class Libraries." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing